# OverloadedStrings not quite working

Tags: haskell

This code gives the following error. How can I fix it?

```
230     let pipeline = [ ["$match" =: matchSelect],
231                         ["$group" =: ["_id" =: empty, "sum" =:
232                             ["$sum" =: "$score"]]] ]

Add.hs:232:40:
    No instance for (Data.String.IsString v0)
      arising from the literal `"$score"'
    The type variable `v0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Data.String.IsString Data.Text.Internal.Text
        -- Defined in `Data.Text'
      instance Data.String.IsString [Char] -- Defined in `Data.String'
    In the second argument of `(=:)', namely `"$score"'
    In the expression: "$sum" =: "$score"
    In the second argument of `(=:)', namely `["$sum" =: "$score"]'
Failed, modules loaded: Utils, Delete, Get, Migrate, Review, Validate.
```

Comment: What's the type of (=:) ?

Comment: `(=:) :: Val v => Label -> v -> Field`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(=:)` has a polymorphic type where the type variable mentioned in the argument isn't mentioned in the result type, so that the compiler doesn't have enough to decide the types of its second argument in the expression `"$sum" =: "$score"`.

The string literal `"$score"` gives the constraint `IsString v0`, and `(=:)` gives the constraint `Val v0`, but nothing actually says "it must be this type", and since the end result is type `Field` which doesn't mention `v`, nothing about the way the end result is used can constrain `v`.

The simplest thing would be to give `"$score"` a type signature, e.g. `("$score" :: String)` or whatever other type you actually want.